# Animating removeFromSuperview

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation

I'd like to animate the transition from a subview back to the super view.

I display the subview using:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"curlup" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
[self.view addSubview:self.mysubview.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The above works fine.  It's going back to the super view that I don't get any animation:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"curldown" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Is there something different I should be doing to get the subview to animate when removed?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you need to do `forView:self.view.superview` instead, to be consistent with what you are doing when you are adding, because in this case the `self.view` is the child, and so you would need to do it on the parent.

Answer (score 112):

If you're targeting iOS 4.0 upwards you can use animation blocks instead:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
     animations:^{view.alpha = 0.0;}
     completion:^(BOOL finished){ [view removeFromSuperview]; }];
```

(above code comes from [Apple's UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animatewithduration))

Comment: alas! I always thought *removing* takes 0.2 seconds. But the removing happens instantaneously. The *alpha changes*, take 0.2 seconds. If we set it to 200seconds again still the removal from superview would be instantaneous, but it won't happen until 200 seconds have passed...

Answer (score 26):

JosephH answer in Swift:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {view.alpha = 0.0}, 
                                completion: {(value: Bool) in
                                              view.removeFromSuperview()
                                            })
```

Answer (score 6):

Although approach with sending `removeFromSuperview` message from animation completion block works fine for most cases, sometimes there is no way to prevent a view from immediate removal from view hierarchy.

For example, `MKMapView` removes its subviews after it receives message `removeAnnotations`, and there is no "animated" alternative for this message in the API.

Nonetheless the following code allows you to do whatever you like with a visual clone of a view after it's been removed from superview or even deallocated:

```
UIView * snapshotView = [view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
snapshotView.frame = view.frame;
[[view superview] insertSubview:snapshotView aboveSubview:view];

// Calling API function that implicitly triggers removeFromSuperview for view
[mapView removeAnnotation: annotation];

// Safely animate snapshotView and release it when animation is finished
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     snapshotView.alpha = 0.0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [snapshotView removeFromSuperview];
                 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Example below:

```
func removeSpinningGear(cell: LocalSongsCollectionViewCell) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: {
        cell.spinningGearBtn.alpha = 0.0
    }) { _ in
        cell.spinningGearBtn.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```